# How to get to level 40 and beyond in The Witcher 3

Tags: the-witcher-3

Currently I'm level 39 and I have finished the main story, HoS expansion and all the witcher contracts. My question is where do I go to quest, kill monsters to get to lvl40 and beyond so I can use the Black unicorn sword.

Comment: Why don't you start a New Game+ ? This allows you to use your save with your level/items/stuff and do the plot one more time, this time with enemies scaling to your level, which means faster exp.

Comment: All to use that sword? But wouldn't you need a worthy enemy to fight?

Answer (score 4):

You have three options

1. Grind and explore, very slow, even if you happen upon another new quest.
2. Start a newgame+, which scales everything up to your level, allows you to play everything again.
3. Wait for the [Blood & Wine expansion](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_and_Wine) (will be released in summer, current rumors say 7th of June), which will certainly provide additional content to get past lvl 40.

Personally, I went with option 3, my character is currently Level 39 as well.